# Failed Autowired of BuildProperties Spring Boot 2.1.5 & eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I'm creating a very simple application with a few REST API's and it's currently working correctly until I try to use the BuildProperties on my health check API. While starting my application I get the following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-17 09:54:29.210 ERROR 10796 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field buildProperties in com.controller.HealthCheck required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'buildProperties' in 'ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnResource did not find resource '${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' in your configuration.
```

I went to the build file and I also looked in the jar file created by the build and I see the build-info.properties is in fact there. In the jar file the path to the file is "BOOT-INF\classes\META-INF\". I also have other "Autowired" elements that are not having issues.

Where my code fails:

```
@RestController
public class HealthCheck {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Autowired 
    BuildProperties buildProperties;


    @GetMapping("/health")
    public HealthCheckResponse healthCheck() {
        return getHealthCheckResponse();
    }

    private HealthCheckResponse getHealthCheckResponse(){
        HealthCheckResponse healthResponse = new HealthCheckResponse();
        String[] profiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();

        healthResponse.setServerTime(new Date());
        healthResponse.setVersion(buildProperties.getVersion());
        healthResponse.setEnvironment(profiles[0]);

        return healthResponse;
    }
```

My gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.3'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.5.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '12'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('snippetsDir', file("build/generated-snippets"))
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:2.1.1'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-webtestclient'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
}

asciidoctor {
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

build-info.properties:

```
#Properties
#Mon Jun 17 10:52:04 EDT 2019
build.version=0.0.1
build.group=com
build.name=app
build.artifact=app
build.time=2019-06-17T14\:52\:04.829909200Z
```

Comment: Are you using Intelli J ?

Comment: no, I'm using eclipse. I pasted my gradle build file content too just in case it's some known issue with one of the plugins like the eclipse plugin or something else.

Comment: Which version of JDK are you running your spring-boot application ?

Comment: Do you have any of those defined in your project: '@SpringBootApplication' or '@EnableAutoConfiguration' ?

Comment: Can you also please put the content of build-info.properties in the question, please ?

Comment: @BorislavMarkov openJDK 12, I have "@SpringBootApplication" on my main class and the resulting build-info.properties is:

    #Properties
    #Mon Jun 17 10:52:04 EDT 2019
    build.version=0.0.1
    build.group=com
    build.name=app
    build.artifact=app
    build.time=2019-06-17T14\:52\:04.829909200Z

Comment: Can you also mention how you start the process, is it from command line or from eclipse? Do you have the same failure when you start with java -jar <jarname>?

Comment: I start it using the spring boot plugin on eclipse, "right click the project" -> "run as" or "debug as" -> Spring Boot App. I have not tried running it from the command line, I'll post the results shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Borislav Markov suggested I tried running it via command line and it seems to work perfectly regardless if I use JDK 12 or JDK 8. I think the issue has to do with the eclipse plugin I am using to run the application via the IDE.

Comment: For my case I am using Intellij I did the following: settings > build > gradle > runner > check delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle

Comment: @user666 This is now under settings > build, execution, deployment > build tools > Gradle and then a feature called "Build and run using".

Comment: I faced this issue with maven and IDEA.  The "Generate Sources and update folder for all projects" option of maven worked for me.

Answer (score 101):

Just run a `mvn clean package` and then restart the spring boot application from either Eclipse/IntelliJ.

Comment: Works, thank you! `mvn clean package`.

Comment: This worked for me. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @JamesHackett This file (build-info.properties) is read by Spring from your classpath META-INF/ folder. By doing this it is built there by your build tool (maven, gradle, etc.)

Comment: It works! I had the same problem using @Configuration file. It happened after launch other project.

Comment: "mvn -U clean install" also works.

Comment: works in 2023 also!

Comment: Still works in March of 2023

Answer (score 40):

Add/Modify at the end of pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <finalName>{NAME_YOUR_PROJECT}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 19):

**In short:** This problem is IDE related (I'm checked on Eclipse and Idea), and this is not affecting running/debugging spring boot application in startup scripts over the gradle build system.

Also, premise that boot plugin for eclipse and JDK are producing this problem is not entirely correct.

**Root of this problem:** Different location of build artifacts which are compiled with different compilers and missing `build-info.properties`.

**Explanation:**

When gradle performs the build, it ussually uses JDK compiler to produce Java artifacts and output is placed into build directory.

On the other side, when eclipse performs the build, it produces arifacts with Eclipse JDT and output is placed into bin directory.

Note that mixing those two could lead to unexpected behaviours. This 'feature' is already analyzed by eclipse team and it is rejected (closed as invalid). More information [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472100).

According to fact that gradle task `buildInfo` is ran by gradle, that is explaining the fact that `build-info.properties` file exists in gradle's default output folder (by default it has to be located here: `build/resources/main/META-INF/`).

From @ROOTKILL's question, visible is that he is tried to obtain information from BuildProperties class. Under the hood, when Spring detects there is build-info.properties file on the classpath, it creates BuildProperties bean unless it is explicitly declared.
Useful information is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/968a637e50a67c4aa2ab2ecf70519851b9cd79b7/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/info/ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.java#L66).

Please, take a look at this method:

```
@ConditionalOnResource(resources = "${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@Bean
public BuildProperties buildProperties() throws Exception {
    return new BuildProperties(
            loadFrom(this.properties.getBuild().getLocation(), "build"));
}
```

According to the fact that IDE is using different output dir, there is missing build-info.properties file and this produces displayed error (`Bean method 'buildProperties' in 'ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnResource did not find resource '${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}'`).
And on other side, this explains why everything is runnable with gradle.

**Solution:**

According to those facts, solution is clear: Both eclipse and IntelliJ Idea IDE's must use gradle's tasks instead of it's own for running/debugging.

- For the **Eclipse IDE**: Application can be started over the gradle task (bootRun from gradle tasks view).
- For the **Idea IDE**: There can be added setting that delegates IDE build/run actions to gradle, which is @user666 already pointed before.

Since this solution uses gradle, `build-info.properties` file will be used from `build/resources/main/META-INF/` location (gradle's default), and off course it will be visible. As a consequence, bean BuildProperties will be created and will be usable.

Answer (score 18):

As correctly mentioned by [@André Schonrock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58081353/8370915), the cause of issue is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-build-info):

> Both the Maven plugin and the Gradle plugin allow generating build
> information containing the coordinates, name, and version of the
> project. The plugins can also be configured to add additional
> properties through configuration. When such a file is present, Spring
> Boot auto-configures a BuildProperties bean.

So you need either to add for `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in `POM`:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>build-info</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

or to add in `build.gradle`:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

As alternative way can be explicitly added `Bean` in a shorter form than was shown by [@djangofan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034087/8370915):

```
@Bean @ConditionalOnMissingBean(BuildProperties.class)
BuildProperties buildProperties() {
    return new BuildProperties(new Properties());
}
```

in configuration file.

**Notice:** if you updated `POM` or `build.gradle`, but the error still appears, try to use (e.g. for `Maven`) lifecycle commands `clean` and then `install`  and run again the project.

Comment: Alternative solution mentioned above is a fix, it's not leading to a solution.
You may end up, breaking business requirement with that.

Answer (score 15):

If using Intelli and maven, here is screenshot on how to change the runner and use maven runner. Ideally this is best suggested, as we can run exactly how maven runs in the ide also.

[image]

Comment: This did the trick for me... good tip

Comment: Solved here! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My Spring Boot service has a Maven  build-info section in the maven-spring-boot plugin and so I get this error `BuildProperties cannot be found` when I try to run the service when it is not from a .jar archive.   So, to run my service as a regular Spring Boot run configuration, I had to add this condition bean and now everything works , both as a .jar  release  and also it runs as a debug non-release:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@Bean
public BuildProperties buildProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("group", "com.example");
    properties.put("artifact", "demo");
    properties.put("version", "not-jarred");
    return new BuildProperties(properties);
}
```

Comment: This is a wrong solution, when you want to use original build-info.properties. This method override default Spring conditional mechanism always.

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. Ideally, the properties should be auto-loaded from the build-info.properties or should come from pom.xml or build.gradle and injected in.

Comment: It's a fix, not solution of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using lombok, make sure to exclude it configuration for spring-boot-maven-plugin, e.g.,

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                </exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>build-info</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have made clear, this is due to the IDE not creating the file. For vscode, I solved it by defining a task to copy the **build-info.properties** file from Gradle's **build/resources/main/META-INF** directory into vscode's **bin/main/META-INF** so that it would be where the build expects to find it.

Normally I have run a Gradle build recently, and that slightly stale version of build-info.properties is good enough for my debugging run in vscode.

Create a **.vscode/tasks.json** similar to this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            // This task keeps vscode from failing when using BuildProperties
            "label": "Copy build-info from Gradle",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "mkdir -p ./bin/main/META-INF/ && cp ./build/resources/main/META-INF/build-info.properties ./bin/main/META-INF/build-info.properties"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then add the task as a **preLaunchTask** in your **.vscode/launch.json**:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Spring Boot-Application<example>",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "mainClass": "com.example.Application",
            "projectName": "example",
            "args": "",
            "preLaunchTask": "Copy build-info from Gradle"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'm persevering with vscode for java dev, so this helped a lot. Do you happen to know if this is a bug in vscode itself? Or presumably the java extension?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try running under JDK 8 and to run from the command line with 
`java -jar <your jar name>` just to be sure you get the build properties correctly.

Maybe Jdk 12 is not suitable for spring-boot yet. I think you might have other problems as well. Many Java frameworks are not 100% certified that they will work with JDK 12.

I think the plan is to officially support Java 12 as of Spring Boot 2.2

Comment: I ran the application in the command line with both JDK 8 and JDK 12 and they seem to be running fine via command line. It appears to be related to the spring boot plugin for eclipse. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your IDE is confused by the fact that the "fat jar" overwrites the normal jar. The IDE understands the classpath of the normal jar + generated resource of `build-info.properties.

I always build the jars under different names, so I can avoid this kind of issues with partial builds.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal

> To avoid the executable archive and the normal archive from being written to the same location, one or the other should be configured to use a different location. One way to do so is by configuring a classifier:

```
bootJar {
    classifier = 'boot'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/968a637e50a67c4aa2ab2ecf70519851b9cd79b7/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/info/ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.java#L66) solution and thought it was better to use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean (BuildProperties.class)` instead
`@ConditionalOnResource (resources = "$ {spring.info.build.location: classpath: META-INF / build-info.properties}")`.

Because I can control the way `BuildProperties` are created:

```
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(BuildProperties.class)
    @Bean
    public BuildProperties buildProperties() throws IOException {
            Resource r = this.properties.getBuild().getLocation();
            if (r.exists())
                // build-info.properties exists in my jar
                return new BuildProperties(
                    loadFrom(r, "build")); // see ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration code
            else {
                // No, we running via IDE. So let's build a stub:
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.put("group", "com.example");
                properties.put("artifact", "demo");
                properties.put("version", "not-jarred");
                return new BuildProperties(properties);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle Project: add this on **build.gradle** file

```
    springBoot {
        buildInfo {
            properties {
                name = PROJECT_NAME
                additional = [
                        'yourCustomInfo': 'someInfo'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! If I'd like to have a field named `build.version` that has the value of `version` in my build.gradle, how would I access that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is STS and Intellij doesn't run the buildinfo task while running the application as a Spring Boot Application. Since most developers run the app through this mechanism rather than using gradle / maven build need to have a solution that works for both. I followed Sergey K's answer and it worked for IDE based Spring boot run. But for gradle run it failed because the BuildProperties was getting autowired from the Configuration file instead of the generated build-info.properties file.

I was able to overcome this by having the following Component and autowiring it

```
@Component
public BuildValues{
   @Autowired(required = false)
   private buildProperties;
   
   public getBuildProperties(){
       if(buildProperties==null) {
          ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
          Resource r = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:META-INF/build- 
        info.properties");
    if (r.exists()) {
        // build-info.properties exists in my jar
        Properties prop = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(r);
        buildProperties =  new BuildProperties(prop);
    }else {
    // No, we running via IDE. So let's build a stub:
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("buildTime", "2022-01-13T14:38:06.567Z");
        buildProperties = new BuildProperties(properties);
    }
    }
    return buildProperties;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others rightly pointed, the problem is with the IDE. For IntelliJ, the alternative solution is modifying the spring-boot:build-info to "Execute After Rebuild" as shown below.
[image]