# Gradle Spring boot failed with error "required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' that could not be found."

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

Whenever I tries to run spring boot application from eclipse I get an error saying,

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.abcd.documentgenerator.configuration.controller.AppVersionController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' in your configuration.
```

But when I run the similar application through command line with
**gradlew bootrun**, then it works fine. I am not sure what issue is with eclipse. I have added the code below. My task is to get version info from the gradle.

**AppVersionController.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.abcd.documentgenerator.configuration.model.AppVersion;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;

@RestController
public class AppVersionController {
    private final BuildProperties buildProperties;
    public AppVersionController(BuildProperties properties) {
        buildProperties = properties;
    }
    
    @SneakyThrows
    @GetMapping("/appVersion")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public AppVersion getVersion() {
        AppVersion appVersion = new AppVersion();
        appVersion.setVersionId(buildProperties.getVersion());
        return appVersion;
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.12.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
        id 'pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release' version '1.13.6'
    }
    
group = 'com.abcd'
archivesBaseName = 'microservice-abcd'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
version = scmVersion.version
springBoot {
    buildInfo ()
}
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634081/failed-autowired-of-buildproperties-spring-boot-2-1-5-eclipse helps you?

Comment: Hi @Nemanja, I have already tried the solution, but it didn't work for me. Can you help me with better approach?